# How to calculate resolution of pinhole camera?

Tags: optics, diffraction

I am 60 years old. I'm not a student and this is not homework (despite somebody trying to close it as a "homework question".)

I'm interested in building a long-focal-length pinhole camera (by "long" I mean 1 to 10 meters). I'm aware that will involve very long exposures and am planning to used a Peltier-cooled CCD for an imager (except maybe for solar viewing).

But I'd like to know if it's worth bothering - how much resolution can I expect, given a pinhole size and focal length (hole-to-sensor distance)? Will diffraction make this entirely pointless?

How would I go about calculating the expected resolution - clearly (to me) there's a contribution from the hole size (resolution will drop with a bigger hole), but diffraction will increase as the hole gets smaller.

Surely there must be some well-known formula for calculating this - what is it?

Comment: A decade ago I found a source that went through this analysis in the context of solar observations. The result was that if you use a standard paper hole punch in a piece of paper or tinfoil, you can get a hand- sized image of the sun about ten meters away with enough resolution to track sunspots from day to day. If I am able to find the link I'll add it later (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: I'd guess the limit is due to diffraction by the pinhole, which forms an [Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk). Then the angular resolution will be given by $\sin\theta = 1.22\lambda/d$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light and $d$ is the pinhole diameter.

Comment: @JohnRennie Clearly not all pinhole camera configurations are diffraction limited. Consider a 1 inch "pinhole" positioned 1 inch from the film/sensor. (focal length 1 inch). The blurring in that case is obviously dominated by the size of the hole, not diffraction.

Comment: Good point ....

Comment: [This PDF link](http://coconinoastro.org/PDF/OBSERVING%20SUNSPOTS%20USING%20A%20PINHOLE%20CAMERA.pdf) is the document I remembered.  There is a competition among the diffraction-limited resolution, the observing distance at which the pinhole is "small," and the brightness of the projected image.

Comment: Whenever I see something about a pinhole camera resolution I think of [this image](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7bb3022748808ab1f7d9302941b20f33-pjlq) from Optics by Hecht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, both "wave effects" (i.e. diffraction effects) and "ray effects" (i.e. simply geometric effects) will be observed in a pinhole camera. The theoretical resolution is given by the sum of these two effects. For a pinhole camera of diameter $d$, depth $l'$, the resolution (or "spot width") $U$ is given by:

$$U_{tot} = U_{wave} + U_{ray} = \bigg(1.22l'\frac{\lambda}{d}\bigg) + d\frac{(l+l')}{l}$$

...for an object a lateral distance $l$ from the pinhole.

See: [The Pinhole Camera and Image Resolution](https://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg232/lab9.pdf)

*(note a change in notation: this author uses $s$ and $s'$ to denote the camera depth and lateral distance to the object)*

Comment: Note that for the Sun, $l\gg l'$ and so the second term ist just $d$. You don't want either term to dominate, and so you want $1.22l'\lambda = d^2$